# Convert Response into Comma Separated Text in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup I am trying to grab some keywords from a website. However I am getting the texts in new lines and don't have any idea how to turn each response into comma separated text.

My Code:

```
   with open("tags.txt", "a") as f_out:
        for inp in soup.select('#group-keywords a'):
            keywords = inp.getText()
            readykeywords = keywords.replace('\n', ',')
            print(readykeywords, sep="\n", file=f_out)
```

The target HTML looks like this:

```
<ul style="user-select: auto;" class="selectorgadget_selected">
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/fast-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Fast</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/fresh-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Fresh</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/line-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Line</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/paper-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Paper</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/house-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">House</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/aroma-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Aroma</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fast
Fresh
Line
....
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Fast, Fresh, Line ...
```

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the edit. I will keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<ul style="user-select: auto;" class="selectorgadget_selected">
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/fast-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Fast</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/fresh-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Fresh</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/line-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Line</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/paper-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Paper</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/house-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">House</a>
    </li>
    <li style="user-select: auto;"><a href="/royalty-free-vectors/aroma-vectors" class="selectorgadget_suggested" style="user-select: auto;">Aroma</a>
    </li>
</ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

with open("tags.txt", "w") as f_out:
    tags = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in soup.select("a")]
    print(*tags, sep=", ", file=f_out)
```

Creates `tags.txt`:

```
Fast, Fresh, Line, Paper, House, Aroma
```